# Data-toggle colapse wont display the right target in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a data-toggle in `tr` and once click,the underlying `tr` will display in the last part of all the `tr`. Example: If I click the name John, its corresponding `tr` with `<td>test2</td>` will display in the last part.Let us say, it will display under Genrevel. What is wrong with my javascript?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#example1").DataTable();

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css">

<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Level</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionOne"> Joseph</a></td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="demo1" class="accordian-body collapse">
      <td>test 1</td>
      <td>test 1</td>
      <td>test 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionOne"> John</a></td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="accordionOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <td>test 2</td>
      <td>test 2</td>
      <td>test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionTwo"> Genrevel</a></td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="accordionTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <td>test 3</td>
      <td>test 3</td>
      <td>test 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: w8 what an accordion in a datatable? why?

Comment: Your example works as expected. What problem are you actually having?

Comment: @madalinivascu - See this link http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=accordion.This is my source which I want to achieve in my project but its not working.That is why I've posted this hoping someone has the idea on what is goin on.

Comment: @TiesonT. - Sir the problem is if i click any of the name, its sub tr will display in another collapsible row or always in the last collapsible tr.

Comment: @Gatzmar remove the datatable and this should work as a accordeon